# Is this a rafter tie or something else?

Tags: attic, structural

House was built in 1978. I'm acquainting myself with some of the basics of the attic structure. I don't know what this is called or the purpose it serves. Specifically I am referring to the 2x6 turned in it's side which is then connected to a 2x4. Can anyone tell me?

UPDATE
All I have is video and taking stills from a video come out blurry. I trimmed a video down to about 20sec (safe for work - age restricted so kids don't crawl around in an attic space). https://youtu.be/AePGvTDzQfY

[image]

UPDATE 2
after watching some YouTube videos, the L shaped tie appears to be nothing more than joist support to keep the joists running parallel. I can safely remove those as the 5/8" plywood decking going down will take it's place.

Comment: That picture leaves it very difficult to tell what's going on there. Got any others?

Comment: It looks like a walkway/foot path.

Comment: What is the attic framing and in what configuration? What is under the plywood?

Comment: I've added a short video to show the boards in question. Safe for work viewing. Age restricted so kids don't get the idea of crawling around attics with  fecal matter and get sick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching some YouTube videos, the L shaped tie appears to be nothing more than joist support to keep the joists running parallel to each other. I can safely remove those as the 5/8" plywood decking going down will take it's place.